# Simplifying $\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sin\frac\pi{2^{k+3}}+\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

I have recently stumbled upon the sequence $\left( u_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined as follows :

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, ~ u_n = \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left[ \: \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+3}} \right) + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \: \right] $$

and **I am trying to find a more concise expression of its general term (ie without the $\boldsymbol{\prod}$ sign).**

Firstly, one can easily see that :

$$\begin{align*} 
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, ~ u_n &= \: \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \: \left[ \: \sin \bigg( \dfrac{\pi}{4} \bigg) + \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+3}} \right) \: \right] \\
&= \: \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \: \left[ \: 2 \times \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} + \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+4}} \right) \times \cos \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} - \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+4}} \right) \: \right] \\
&= \: 2^n \times \left[ \: \: \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \: \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} + \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+4}} \right) \: \right] \times \left[ \: \: \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \: \cos \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} - \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+4}} \right) \: \right] \quad ( * )
\end{align*}$$

But after that, I had a lot of trouble trying to simplify $\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \: \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} + \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+4}} \right)$ and $\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \: \cos \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} - \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+4}} \right)$, and eventually got stuck. **Am I heading in the right direction ? How can I simplify $\boldsymbol{u_n}$ even more ?**

I also found that :

$$\newcommand{\isEquivTo}[1]{\underset{#1}{\sim}}
u_n \isEquivTo{+ \infty} \dfrac{C}{\left( \sqrt{2} \right)^n}$$

where $C \approx 2.564448944368$, if it can help. **I am also trying to figure out the literal expression of $\boldsymbol{C}$ (ideally, in terms of fundamental constants only).**

####################################################################

**UPDATE/EDIT :**

While I did **not** manage to find a simplified expression of $u_n$, I think I did make some progress.

$1)$ Firstly, since the sequence $( ( \sqrt{2} )^n \, u_n )_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges (towards $C$), I find it convenient to let :

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, ~ v_n = ( \sqrt{2} )^n \, u_n = \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left[ \: 1 + \sqrt{2} \, \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+3}} \right) \right]$$

Finding the expression of $u_n$ is now equivalent to finding the expression of $v_n$.

$2)$ In order to make the following points easier to read, let :

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \,
\begin{cases}
\, c_n = \cos \left( \dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+4}} \right) \\[10pt]
\, s_n = \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+4}} \right) \\[10pt]
\, f(n) = \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \, \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} + \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+4}} \right) \\[10pt]
\, g(n) = \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \, \cos \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} - \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+4}} \right)
\end{cases}
$$

Then, by $( * )$, we have : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, v_n = ( 2 \sqrt{2} )^n \times f(n) \times g(n)$

$3)$ My idea was then to rewrite $f(n)$, $g(n)$ and $f(n) \times g(n)$ as "polynomial expressions" of $\cos \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right)$ and $\sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right)$. In order to achieve this, notice the following :

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \,
\begin{cases}
\, f(n) = \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \, \left[ s_k \cos \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) + c_k \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \right] \\[10pt]
\, g(n) = \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \, \left[ c_k \cos \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) + s_k \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \right]
\end{cases}
$$

We can then use a generalization of Newton's binomial expansion to obtain :

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \,
\begin{cases}
\, f(n) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \, F_n(k) \times \cos^k \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \times \sin^{n-k} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \\[10pt]
\, g(n) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \, G_n(k) \times \cos^k \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \times \sin^{n-k} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right)
\end{cases}
$$

where :

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, \forall k \in \left[ 0,  n \right], \, F_n (k) = 
\begin{cases}
\, \sum\limits_{0 \, \leq \, i_1 \, < \, \dots \, < \, i_k \, \leq \, n-1} \, \left( \, \prod\limits_{l=1}^{k} s_{i_l} \times \prod\limits_{ \substack{m=0 \\ m \notin \{ i_1, \, \dots \, , \, i_k \} } }^{n-1} c_m \, \right) \quad \mathrm{if} \, \, k \neq 0 \\[10pt]
\, \prod\limits_{m=0}^{n-1} c_m \quad \mathrm{if} \, \, k = 0
\end{cases}
$$

and :

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, \forall k \in \left[ 0,  n \right], \, G_n (k) = 
\begin{cases}
\, \sum\limits_{0 \, \leq \, i_1 \, < \, \dots \, < \, i_k \, \leq \, n-1} \, \left( \, \prod\limits_{l=1}^{k} c_{i_l} \times \prod\limits_{ \substack{m=0 \\ m \notin \{ i_1, \, \dots \, , \, i_k \} } }^{n-1} s_m \, \right) \quad \mathrm{if} \, \, k \neq 0 \\[10pt]
\, \prod\limits_{m=0}^{n-1} s_m \quad \mathrm{if} \, \, k = 0
\end{cases}
$$

One can note that : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, \forall k \in \left[ 0, n \right], \, G_n(n-k) = F_n(k)$

$4)$ We can then prove that :

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, f(n) \times g(n) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n} \, \beta_n(i) \times \cos^i \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \times \sin^{2n-i} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right)$$

where :

$$\begin{align*}
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, \forall i \in \left[ 0, 2n \right], \, \beta_n(i) &= \sum\limits_{k \, = \, \max(i-n, \, 0)}^{\min(i, \, n)} \, F_n(k) \times G_n(i-k) \\[10pt]
&= \sum\limits_{k \, = \, \max(i-n, \, 0)}^{\min(i, \, n)} \, F_n(k) \times G_n(n-(n+k-i)) \\[10pt]
&= \sum\limits_{k \, = \, \max(i-n, \, 0)}^{\min(i, \, n)} \, F_n(k) \times F_n(n+k-i)
\end{align*}$$

We can also note this very nice property : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, \forall i \in \left[ 0, 2n \right], \, \beta_n(i) = \beta_n(2n-i) \quad \quad \quad ( ** )$

$5)$ Therefore, we have :

$$\begin{align*}
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, v_n &= (2 \sqrt{2})^n \times \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n} \, \beta_n(i) \times \cos^i \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \times \sin^{2n-i} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \\[10pt]
&= (2 \sqrt{2})^n \times \sin^{2n} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \times \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n} \, \beta_n(i) \times \cot^i \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right)
\end{align*}
$$

But, since we have $\cos \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) = \dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}} \,$ and $\, \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) = \dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}} \,$, we then obtain :

$$\forall n  \in \mathbb{N}, \, v_n = ( \sqrt{2} - 1 )^n \times \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n} \, \beta_n(i) \times ( 1 + \sqrt{2} )^i \quad \quad \quad \quad ( *** )$$

But, by $( ** )$, we also have ($i \leftrightarrow 2n-i$) :

$$\begin{align*}
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, v_n &= (2 \sqrt{2})^n \times \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n} \, \beta_n(i) \times \cos^{2n-i} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \times \sin^{i} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \\[10pt]
&= (2 \sqrt{2})^n \times \cos^{2n} \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \times \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n} \, \beta_n(i) \times \tan^i \left( \dfrac{\pi}{8} \right) \\[10pt]
&= ( 1 + \sqrt{2} )^n \times \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n} \, \beta_n(i) \times ( \sqrt{2} - 1 )^i \quad \quad \quad \quad ( *** \, * )
\end{align*}
$$

$6)$ Thus, since $u_n = \dfrac{v_n}{\left( \sqrt{2} \right)^n}$, we finally obtain, by $(***)$ and $(*** \, *)$ :

$$\boxed{
\begin{align*}
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, u_n &= \left( 1 - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) ^n \times \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n} \, \beta_n(i) \times ( 1 + \sqrt{2} )^i \\[10pt]
&= \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) ^n \times \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n} \, \beta_n(i) \times ( \sqrt{2} - 1 )^i
\end{align*}
}
$$

I find these expressions of $u_n$ really intriguing, since the sums remind me **a lot** of the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{2n}$. Indeed, $(1+x)^{2n}= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n} \, \binom{2n}{i} \times x^i$. Additionally, the fact that $\binom{2n}{i}$ equals $\binom{2n}{2n-i}$ is analogous to $(**)$ ...

$7)$ My hope was that I could *finally* finish this off by simplifying $\beta_n(i)$. Yet, I still haven't managed to do so. However, here are some particular values of $\beta_n(i)$ :

$$\begin{cases}
\, \beta_n(0) = \beta_n(2n) = \dfrac{1}{2^n} \times \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \, \sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+3}} \right) \quad \quad (\forall n \geq 0) \\[10pt]
\, \beta_n(1) = \beta_n(2n-1) = 2 \times \beta_n(0) \times \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \, \dfrac{1}{\sin \left( \dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+3}} \right)} \quad \quad (\forall n \geq 1) \\[10pt]
\, \beta_n(n) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \, F_n(k)^2 \quad \quad (\forall n \geq 0) \\[10pt]
\end{cases} 
$$

**What more can be done with $\boldsymbol{\beta_n}$ ?**

**Side note : everything claimed in this post was proved by hand, but was also double-checked numerically using Python.**

Comment: Have you proved your last claim or was the expression found numerically?

Comment: Yes I proved it. Firstly, I used the fact that, for any given sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\:$ which has a **positive** general term, we have the following :

$$\prod\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+a_n)<\infty\iff\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n<\infty\quad\quad(1)$$

Moreover, note that :  

$$\exists\:C>0,~u_n\sim\dfrac{C}{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^n}\iff\prod\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1+\sqrt{2}\:\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+3}}\right)\right)<\infty\quad\quad(2)$$

Comment: Then, combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ provides :

$$\exists\:C>0,~u_n\sim\dfrac{C}{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^n}\iff \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sqrt{2}\:\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+3}}\right)<\infty\quad\quad(3)$$

Additionally, since $\sqrt{2}\:\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+3}}\right)\sim\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{2^{n+3}}$, by using the fact that 2 series with equivalent **(positive)** general terms have the same behaviour, we obtain that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sqrt{2}\:\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+3}}\right)<\infty$. Then $(3)$ provides the result.

Comment: +1 just for the **extensive** computations you tried

Answer (score 0):

The constant
$$C=2.5644489443678944047798215524306850491345921029196$$ ($50$ exact figures) is obtained for $n=166$.

It is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

Just a coincidence, it is "close" to 
$$10 \sin \left(\frac{5 \pi }{36}\right) \sin \left(\frac{11 \pi }{53}\right)=2.5644482$$

Comment: Nice coincidence. The fact that it doesn't get recognized by ISCs is extremely intriguing.